# Urllib.request and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, loops, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I have a dictionary in which the key is and imdb id and the value is a release year for said imdb id. e.g. `dictionary.key = 1898069    dictionary.value ="2017"`

My issue with the code below is that when I `print(x[foo_indexes[0]].split("(", 1)[0].strip())` its perfectly clean e.g. Netflix

but when I try to append to a list e.g. `dist.append(x[foo_indexes[0]].split("(", 1)[0].strip())` I get all of the HTML code pre-cleaning and each show copies over the last.

I took it step by step and it's at the print/append stage that the issue occurs. Can anyone point to the issue? Thank you.

```
dist = []
for imdb, ry in imdb_year.items():    
    url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt"+imdb+"/companycredits?ref_=tt_ql_dt_4"
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    # soup.title.text
    try:
        dist = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'simpleList'})
        x = dist[1].text.split('\n')

        foo_indexes = [i for i, s in enumerate(x) if ry and "USA" in s]

        dist.append(x[foo_indexes[0]].split("(", 1)[0].strip())
    except:
        dist.append('None')
```

Comment: it's a bit hard because I can't try your code. But what happen if you make dist.append(str(x[foo .... 
?

Comment: you mean `dist = []` not `dist=()`. Beacuse `tupe` does not have method `append`

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo!...also I tried str() to no avail. Very strange that when going step by step it works, right now Im looping with the print statement, printing the return to the cell and going to copy-paste them into a list. Rather if I could just append though :/

Comment: I got it.. you have dist=[] and then another dist with your html... You make happen to your full html... I can post an answer but you should replace
```dist2=[]``` and  ```dist2.append```then

Comment: @Panda50 you're a hero, thank you!

Comment: It will give you an empty list everytime you run it

Comment: what's `ry` in your `foo_indexes`. Is it a variable? or a string?

Comment: @Ajay its a string,  its the releaser year - the value from the dictionary which is looped through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one empty list named `dist` and you use `dist`again as a result of bs4 findall...

Then when you hadd to dist your result it'll add to the dist from bs4!! Here is the corrected answer:

```
dist2 = []
for imdb, ry in imdb_year.items():    
    url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt"+imdb+"/companycredits?ref_=tt_ql_dt_4"
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    # soup.title.text
    try:
        dist = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'simpleList'})
        x = dist[1].text.split('\n')

        foo_indexes = [i for i, s in enumerate(x) if ry and "USA" in s]

        dist2.append(x[foo_indexes[0]].split("(", 1)[0].strip())
    except:
        dist2.append('None')
```